# What is the meaning of <> symbol in Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I am new to SQL and Stored Procedures so I am not sure this is where I should ask this question.

Anyway, in my current project other developers are added many SP into the database. To study how to write SP, I go through some of them. And in one of them I saw a line like below

```
-- several lines of codes
AND pohpoid <> 0 
-- several lines of codes
```

Sp what is this `<>` code really mean in SQL Stored Procedure?

Note : My wild guess is less than or greater than.

Comment: This means `IS NOT EQUAL`.

Comment: It's the same as everywhere else - "not equals". Oddly, "less than or greater than" has the same meaning :-)

Comment: Or same as C's `!=`.

Comment: Then why not just use `!=`

Comment: Because != isn't valid to SQL.

Comment: it means "not equal to"